# Change 'HTML' overflow property upon contact form popup and close out

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I built a custom popup form on my mobile site. Everything is good for the most part except that the background behind the popup div is still scrollable. I know that 'HTML' {overflow:hidden;} will stop it, but I don't know how to execute that action along side the javascript I have that activates the popup.

LINK (View the popup @media max-width: 991px - Click on Email botton on bottom right):

http://www.eastvalleyurban.com/blank-community-template-2

**Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block')
          e.style.display = 'none';
       else
          e.style.display = 'block';
    }
//-->
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="contact-popup-container" style="display: none" class="popup-container">
   <div id="popup-wrapper">
      <div id="popup-contents">
          <div id="close-button"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="toggle_visibility('contact-popup-container');"><i class="fa fa-times fa-lg"></i></a></div>
          <h3>Oh, hi there! How can we help?</h3>
          <p>We are professionals at what we do and what we do is help you with any and all of your real estate needs. Give us a jingle just to chat, or to list your property, either way we'd love to hear from you. Bye!</p>
          <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="3931" title="Contact Form"]' ); ?>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Summary:** I would like to change HTML {overflow:hidden;} upon rollout of the popup and then switch it back to HTML {overflow:visible;} when the popup is closed.

**LINK TO FIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/fo93w7v1/1/

Comment: make a class with `overflow:hidden` and add it to body when you open popup then  remove class on close popup.

Comment: so how do it do that? Where do I put it

Answer (score 0):

First make a css class `hidden` with `overflow : hidden;`.

CSS:

```
.hidden{
  overflow : hidden;
}
```

In  `toggle_visibility` add and remove class to your body(OR html) based on your condition.

JS:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
       var e = document.getElementById(id);
       if(e.style.display == 'block'){
          e.style.display = 'none';
          $('body').removeClass('hidden'); //OR document.body.style.overflow = "scroll";
       }
       else{
          e.style.display = 'block';
          $('body').addClass('hidden');// OR document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
       } 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. After adding the 2 additional lines in the js, the popup doesn't activate now.

Comment: @savphili Then you must be getting some error. See console. Also enclose the code in `$(document).ready...`

Comment: I put $(document).ready(function () { to the beginning and }); to the end and still didn't work. When I add the code $('body').removeClass('hidden'); and .addClass it completely disables the popup and it doesn't activate when I click the button.

Comment: @savphili Perhaps a fiddle with your issue would be helpful, so we can debug easily.

Comment: Here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/fo93w7v1/1/  I can't seem to get the popup to even show up on the fiddle though. My first time using SO and Fiddle. Sorry, I'm just having problems all around.

Comment: @savphili I updated answer and your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fLeekywp/). If you comment `document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";` you will see the scroll. You may not need jquery for this, see the comments in my answer.